# How to resize Jqgrid Datepicker

Tags: jqgrid, datepicker

I need to know how to resize the datepicker in JQGrid. Right now it appears bigger than I want it to. I tried using

```
    jQuery(elem).datepicker({

              autoSize: false,
              height:20,
              width:20,
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true
            });
```

but this does not work.

please help,

thanks

Comment: Do you mean the size of datepicker or the size of the input field near which the datepicker will be created and in which the results of the datepicker will be saved. Where you use datepicker (in search dialog, in searching toolbat, in edit form, in inline edit, ...)

Comment: Hi Oleg, I mean the size of the datepicker itself. I am using it inside the search dialog box. Would the code be different for search toolbar and edit form ?

Comment: I am still not sure that I understand you correctly. Changing of the size of datepicker itself is independent on jqGrid. You can use CSS `.ui-datepicker { width: 30em; }` to change the width of Datepicker windows from default `17em` to `30em`. Is it what you want?

Comment: yes, exactly ! will I be able to find this in the redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css ?

Comment: OK Then I will post the same information as the answer. Probably somebody else will have the same problem. Searching on stackoverflow will not find information from comments.

Comment: thanks oleg ! i tried changing it to 10em from the default 17em, but it does not become any smaller, it stays the same.

Comment: The windows have to hold the required information. Only if you reduce the size of font you will able to reduce the `width`. Try to use `.ui-datepicker {font-size: 6px;}` for example instead of reducing of `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can change the size of jQuery UI Datepicker by specifying CSS properties on `.ui-datepicker`. For example the following CSS

```css
.ui-datepicker { width: 30em; }
```

changes default value of `width` from `17em` to `30em`. The value `30em` is probably too large, but one will clear see that the width of Datepicker are really changed. You can use the value which you find the best for your project.

**UPDATE**: If you need *reduce* the size of datepicker windows you can't just use `width: 10em` because *the content* of the data will be too large to be displayed in the width. What you can do is to reduce the font-size used in the datepicker windows.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FontSizeOfDatepicker.htm) uses

```css
.ui-datepicker { font-size: 8px; }
```

and it displays

[image]

instead of the standard
[image]

Comment: hi, i'm afraid this does not work. also, there is no field like             .ui-datepicker {font-size: 6px;}, so i even tried changiing the font in ui.jqgrid.css but that has no effect on the datepicker, eventhough the grid elements get smaller !

Comment: @user2334092: I posted the demo in **UPDATED** part of my answer which shows the `font-size` do reduces the size of datepicker window.